# how to get a complete css selectors string from a given DOM object

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to write a function

```
function f (domEl){
    //some code here

    //returns a string
}
```

such that:

```
$(f(domEl))[0] == domEl
```

should always return true (of course, regardless at what hierarchy domEl is):

As an example, Let's say:

```
HTML
    body
        ul
            li
            **li**
            li
                ul
                    li
```

and, I want to select bold li element. I get that element and pass that into my function f.

Comment: This doesn't make too much sense to me. Is `domEl` of type `HtmlElement` i.e. that would be returned from `document.getElementById()`?

Comment: neither did it make sense to me, but It was asked as an interview question. But, having css selector string from a DOM element might be useful.

Comment: <ul><li><**li**> is wrong HTML tag. <li> always comes under <ul>. So, How three <li> comes consecutively here ?

Comment: This is nothing to do with hierarchy, `$("<any_selector>")` returns a special `jquery` object and standard javascript returns _"standard"_ `htmlXXElement` types. If you pass a `DOMElement` into `$()` it converts it into a JQuery object. Asking for `$(domEl) == f(domEl)` makes more sense, unless they want you to change the JQuery source.

Comment: @gideon: And `$` means `jQuery` in this code?

Comment: @Umesh It might not be right, but all I am expecting is if it is possible to get a string like "html > body > ul > li:nth(1)" if I pass dom object corresponding to that li to that function.

Comment: @amnotiam aha! :) Hmm I wonder?

Comment: @hrishikeshp19 are you referring to JQuery with `$` ??

Comment: @gideon: I dont know, I am assuming that $("somestring") gives me an array of dom elements matching that selector string.

Comment: @hrishikeshp19: If it gives you an array, or some other collection, then it'll never be `== domEl`

Comment: @amnotiam: edited question before your comment: get first element of that array and compare. Anyway, your answer is conclusive enough. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yeah, I see the edit now. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/vzWgb/

```
function f (domEl){
    var s = [],
        node = domEl;

    do {
        s.unshift(build_nth_selector(node));
    } while((node = node.parentNode) && node !== document.body)

    s.unshift('BODY')

    return s.join(' > ');
}

function build_nth_selector(node) {
    var p = 1,
        n_name = node.nodeName.toUpperCase();
    while (node = node.previousElementSibling)
        ++p;
    return n_name + ':nth-child(' + p + ')'
}

var $ = function(s) { return document.querySelector(s); };

var el = document.getElementById('target');

alert(f(el));

alert($(f(el)) === el);
```

​

The selector looks like this *(for the code I used in the example)*...

```
BODY > DIV:nth-child(1) > DIV:nth-child(1) > UL:nth-child(1) > LI:nth-child(2) > UL:nth-child(1) > LI:nth-child(5)
```

Comment: It's really a smart java script

Comment: I am sorry, but its not working for all cases, have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/vzWgb/2/

Comment: @hrishikeshp19: [Here's an update](http://jsfiddle.net/vzWgb/3/) that builds the `nth-child` selector for each element on the way up. It stops at the `body` assuming that you really don't need to go any further.

Comment: @hrishikeshp19: And [here's another one](http://jsfiddle.net/vzWgb/4/) that simplifies the selector so it will only use `:nth-child()` when there are previous elements, resulting in a cleaner selector `BODY > DIV > DIV > UL > LI:nth-child(2) > UL > LI:nth-child(5)`.

Comment: @hrishikeshp19: And [one more](http://jsfiddle.net/vzWgb/5/) that adds an optimization where if the element has an ID attribute, it simply returns an ID selector, since IDs must be unique on the page.

Comment: your first two updates return false in the end, the last one returns true

Comment: @hrishikeshp19: They all return `true` for me. What sort of browser are you testing in? There is some stuff there that may need some compatibility patches for older browsers.

Comment: chrome is returning false, ff is returning true. funny!, all the code seems to be simple for any interpreter. I am not sure why it is happening. Anyways, thanks a lot..the new one works. :)

Comment: @hrishikeshp19: Well the newest one probably works the target has an ID. If not, it'll work the same as the others. I'm running in Chrome, so it's strange that the others are false for you.